# trouble wih validation inside of asp wizard

Tags: c#

I have a group of 5 textboxes and I am using an asp:wizard. I want to check to see if all of the textboxes are empty I want to fire a label named lblItemBlock. Nothing I have tried has worked so far and so i tried cutting it down even smaller to test. I made the label visible on the page and on the active step tried to set the visible property to false. and for whatever reason it does not work

here is what I have:

```
protected void OnActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex == Wizard1.WizardSteps.IndexOf(this.WizardStep3))
    {
        lblItemBlock.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the textbox/input validator in asp.net

Comment: thats the thing...not all 5 are required only one out of the 5

Comment: I had trouble posting the code here yesterday...here is a link to what I was using...first let me explain. I want to make sure that at least 1 of  the 5 Item textboxes are not empty then I want to check to see if the user entered in a reason for the corrosponding item [link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1818490/5041938.aspx/1?check+to+see+if+a+group+of+textboxes+is+blank+using+asp+wizard)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom validator with client side script.  There is probably a better method with 5 inputs but I use this when I need to validate multiple inputs in unison.  The following checks that at least one of the text boxes has content:

```
function searchValidate(oSrc, args) {
            var fName = document.getElementById('<%= txtFName.ClientID %>').value;
            var mName = document.getElementById('<%= txtMName.ClientID %>').value;
            var lName = document.getElementById('<%= txtName.ClientID %>').value;
            if (fName == "" && mName == "" && lName == "") {
                args.IsValid = false;
            } else {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
```